Relationship between comprehension and analogy
John Von Neumann jokingly said [to Felix Smith]:

Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them.

This seems to mean that, in mathematics at least, there is never a moment where one can say that they have, in their mind, the full picture of what is going on.
Unrelatedly, Simone Weil noted, in pages she wrote during a period she spent working at a factory (translation mine):

As for application, a clear-sighted study would without a doubt show that it relies not on the property of representing the things that would be contained in the signs (occult quality), but on an analogy of the operations.

Which in turn seems to mean that tasks can only be accomplished through the translation of operations - as seen in the mind of the worker - into actual physical actions, through an analogy. Now, Weil was likely influenced by her correspondence with her brother (mathematician André Weil), so there is probably a connection between that statement of hers and the way a mathematician would come to see things in that domain. But she generalizes it and it does not seem like mathematics would have a solid reason to be different from other activities in such a profound aspect.
All I mean is that both of these quotes obviate the idea of comprehension (at least as the notion of the thing necessary to the mind of the worker who applies theory to practice) as composed of the presence in mind not of a full picture, but of sufficient analogies between the operations relevant to the "concept that is being comprehended" and physical actions.
Are there any works that go in depth about the study of comprehension and this question specifically? Do they agree that analogy between the theoretical and the physical is the deepest that "comprehension" can be? Is there another solid conception of comprehension?

"Mathematics may be defined as the subject in which we never know what we are talking about, nor whether what we are saying is true. People who have been puzzled by the beginnings of mathematics will, I hope, find comfort in this definition" (Russell). Not sure if the question is about understanding ("comprehension") in general or in science, mathematics or both, but see some perspectives in SEP, Understanding and Mathematical Explanation.


“A great scientific truth does not triumph by convincing its opponents
and making them see the light, but rather because its opponents
eventually die, and a new generation grows up that is familiar with
it,”
-Max Planck

And that's not just in regard to acceptance of quantum mechanics, Deaths of prominent life scientists tend to be followed by a surge in highly cited research by newcomers. In science, Kuhn described this in terms of paradigm shifts.
I would look foremost to Wittgenstein's discussion of language games, and language as use:

"In this sort of predicament, always ask yourself: How did we learn
the meaning of this word ("good", for instance)? From what sort of
examples? In what language-games? Then it will be easier for you to
see that the word must have a family of meanings."
-Wittgenstein, in Philosophical Investigations

There is no 'final vocabulary' to use Rorty's term. The meanings of words, and yes even math ideas, are necessarily in flux, because we arrived at them through metaphor and analogy, and extend and integrate them similarly, and these are embedded in our modes of life and language games.
Hofstadter's Surfaces and Essences: Analogy as the Fuel and Fire of Thinking is like a general discussion of the topic you raise, in quite informal terms. It should be read against a background of his more thorough book Godel Escher Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid, which I see as describing a computational approach to math and language, toward understanding how comprehension works. It should be noted that there is this big emphasis in academic philosophy on predicate calculus/first-order logic, and Hofstadter goes deeply into what happens if you go well beyond that, with his ideas of Strange Loops and Tangled Hierarchies, which he frames as essential to understanding how minds work and avoid the Halting Problem.
The most direct answer to your questions though is Nancy Cartwright's How The Laws of Physics Lie (PDF of book, included as part of Texas Tech University's Intro to Philosophy of Sci resources).

"The language of capacities seems to me, as I develop it, much closer
to the way that we actually reason without making these additional
terrifically strong metaphysical assumptions. It’s weaker notion than
this notion of exact law and it allows us to account for what we
successfully do without having to have as big a metaphysical leap as
the person who believes everything has an abstract description which
brings it under the laws of physics."
-from How the Laws of Physics Still Lie: an interview with Nancy Cartwright

This is versus the idealist and mathematical-Platonist idea of 'true noumenas', things having essences which can be approached but never arrived at.
You might like to see my account of how the apparent 'universality' of mathematics can be described as emergent from physics plus intersubjectivity, here: The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences


“Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?”
“That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,” said the Cat.
“I don’t much care where—” said Alice.
“Then it doesn’t matter which way you go,” said the Cat.
“—so long as I get somewhere,” Alice added as an explanation.
“Oh, you’re sure to do that,” said the Cat, “if you only walk long enough.”

In mathematics you don't understand things - in the sense that you may start with something that makes a lot of sense, you know that generalizing it would be utter nonsense, and yet you decide: "I'm just going to generalize this and see where it gets me." Mathematics is the jump from well-defined, rigorous sense into generalized, surprising non-sense.
For example -- we know what it means to say that one collection of things has "more" things in it than some other. All our empirical
experience with this is based on working with finite collections. We know that
if a collection has more things than another, it cannot be "contained in" the other. So, the concept of an
infinite set of numbers, treating all the numbers as one well-defined whole, seems tricky and paradoxical. We can pair off
all natural numbers to all even numbers, so the set seems "bigger" than itself. Generalizing the concept of ordinal and cardinal number beyond the domain of finite numbers seems nonsense. "There is no highest number. It's nonsense to ask how many numbers there are." Generalizing the concept of "more" to infinite sets seems crazy. "More? It's all just 'infinite'. How would you compare them? And you just showed that 'more' is paradoxical."
But then a crazy mathematician, Georg Ferdinand Ludwig Philipp Cantor, comes along and says: "You are scared of infinity because you suspect the concept might lead to contradictions. But without defining what we mean by 'infinite' it makes no sense to be afraid of contradictions." And he makes the brilliant jump into nonsense, by defining infinity by that apparently contradictory property! "Let's define a set to be infinite if it can be mapped onto a proper subset of itself." You might say, "Wait, wait, how can you work with that? That's crazy. You're just turning it around and using something you don't understand at all to define infinite?" But the mathematician would simply say, "No, no, no. It might seem crazy. It's surely counter-intuitive -- I guess. But there is nothing wrong with that definition. As such, it's a perfectly clear definition, right? So, let's just see where this gets us." (I'm glossing over the fact that Cantor got a lot of opposition from other mathematicians, especially from Kronecker, when he first came with his approach. But, I think, this underscores the apparent craziness.)
We do understand mathematical concepts or relations by analogy. But is the generalization step, the jump into nonsense, based on analogy? Once we have found some analogy, we may try to stretch it -- even beyond any physical, empirical analogies.
Stretching an analogy until (and beyond?) its breaking point -- that's itself a poor analogy.
Generalization is to an elastic band as analogy is to a bridge.
But sometimes there are no bridges. Mathematical discovery is like a jump into the dark.
For a nice introduction into mathematical craziness, see What does it feel like to invent math, Grant Sanderson's intro to 2-adic numbers.
